# Computing this complex line integral over unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to evaluate $$\oint _{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z(2 \overline z^2 +3)^2 (\overline z ^4 +2)^3} dz$$ .
I initially tried using parametrization $u=e^{i \theta}$ and this led me to:

$$\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{i}{z(2 e^{-2iu} +3)^2 (e^{-4iu}+2)^3} du$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Alternatively, I tried to see if I could somehow implement the Cauchy-Integral formula. Using $\overline z =\frac{1}{z}$, I get $$ \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^{15}}{(2+3z^2)^2 (1+2z^4)^3}$$ but I cannot use Cauchy Integral formula since there is no single $(z-a)$ in the denominator...
I also wondered if the Cauchy-Goursat theorem is applicable but there is a singularity at $z=i\frac{2}{3^{1/2}}$ which I'm not sure how to deal with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second approach is fine (except that the numerator should be $z^{13}$) and, in principle, you could then use the residue theorem or partial fraction decomposition, but both approaches lead to insane computations. By the way, your integral is equal to $\frac{\pi i}{36}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos We're supposed to do this without residue theorem since that hasn't been covered yet...

Comment: Then it seems that the only remaing possibility is partial fraction decomposition. Good luck with [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial+fraction+decomposition+z%5E13%2F%28%282%2B3z%29%5E2%281%2B2z%5E4%29%5E3%29).

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for your help. Guess I'll be spending the next few hours on the computational part ><

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I also get $z^{15}$.

Comment: @J.G. You're right. My bad.

Comment: @Meow You could use that when $|a| < 1$, and $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline{D_1(0)}$, then $$\int_{S^1}\frac{f(z)}{(z - a)^{n + 1}}\,dz = 2\pi i \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}.$$ This is a consequence of Cauchy's integral formula. Still there is quite a bit of computation required.

Comment: @Mason Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try out this method too